# Calculating orthogonal movement

Tags: python, orthogonal

A board game of 8 * 8.
One of the players is able to move using orthogonal movement, up to a max of 3 spaces.
How do I calculate the possible steps he can take?

Comment: `(r +/- i, c +/- j)` with `i>=0, j>=0, i+j <= 3`

Answer (score 1):

What you need is called "Manhattan Distance".  It's the distance between two cells using only horizontal and vertical steps.  So, you can compute the list of all cells where the Manhattan distance is 3 or less.  So, consider:

```
M = (0,4)

def mdist(a,b):
    return abs(a[0]-b[0])+abs(a[1]-b[1])

def find_possible(M):
    possibles = []    
    for y in range(ROWS):
        for x in range(COLS):
            md = mdist(M, (x,y))
            if 1 <= md <= 3:
                possibles.append( (x,y) )
    return possibles
```

Comment: Is there a way to limit the list to the valid values, what I mean by valid values on the 8 * 8 board, and discard the other values? @TimRoberts

Comment: @ShayariKalam assuming ROWS and COLS are set correct, this already finds only those values on the board.

Comment: Indeed there are many more performant ways than this if performance is an issue, since this checks the whole board! You could imagine that if you had a 1024x1024 board it would take far longer to check. You could consider restricting `ROWS` to the seven rows centered on `M[1]` and `COLS` to the seven columns centered on `M[0]`.

Comment: I don't quite understand, do you mean to limit the search or in simple words change the values of the `ROWS` and `COLS` to just `M[0] + 3` and `M[1] + 3` respectively?  @AdamSmith

Comment: I was wondering if there was a easy way to do this using the numpy library in python too ?

Comment: If the board is actually 8x8, then this method is just about as performant as spreading outward and checking for valid coordinates.  If the board is much larger, then my way will be slower.

Comment: @ShayariKalam read the code: in this case `y` and `x` will be `0 through ROWS-1` and `0 through COLS-1` respectively. If you could make `y` and `x` instead be `max(0, M[1]-3) through min(ROWS-1, M[1]+3)`, and `max(0, M[0]-3) through min(COLS-1,  M[0]+3)`, it would be slightly more performant. That said -- and as Tim rightly points out -- this is only a naive optimization and if your board really is 8x8 then it is not gaining you much (checking <=49 squares instead of 64, but having to do a bunch of arithmetic and comparisons to do it)

Comment: And that's far from the only way to optimize for performance. Consider [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill), which is basically what you're doing here -- drawing a bound at Manhattan Distance 3 and flood filling.

Comment: But also: [premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil) or whatever. This does seem like YAGNI if your board is only 8x8. Hack together the simplest solution (this one) and call it good.